# How to reference cell color from a different Excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to have the cell in Sheet1 check the corresponding cell in Sheet2 and turn into that cell color (or red) if that cell color is red.

For the people in Automotive in Sheet1, go to Sheet to to check on the # of Previous Jobs. If that cell is colored red, also turn red.

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

Something like below, but I'm not sure how to get started with VBA

```
For Job_Subjects=Automotive 
If Cell2.Interior.Color=255 
Then Cell2.Interior.Color=255
End Sub
```

Comment: I recommend you look for a book or net publication about VBA. It will save you from a lot of wasted time and frustration. Also, learn to search help from the VBA documentation that comes (at least was in earlier versions) with Excel.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should start a new question on this, but I'm currently stuck on the selection process. Making VBA use each individual visible cell name. I tried using Indirect, but having trouble getting it to work. 
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:= xlExpression, Formula1:=_
"INDEX(SHEET2!$2:$2, MATCH(Indirect(B2),SHEET2!$2:$2,0)=4"

Comment: Finance is 2 and Automotive is 2.  Should both be coloured red?